# Reading from a staging 2D texture array in DirectX10

Tags: directx, directx10

I have a DX10 program, where I create an array of 3 16x16 textures, then map, read, and unmap each subresource in turn. I use a single mip level, set resource usage to *staging* and CPU access to *read*. Now, here is the problem:

- Subresource 0 contains 1024 bytes, pitch 64, as expected.
- Subresource 1 contains 512 bytes, pitch 64.
- Subresource 2 contains 256 bytes, pitch 64.

I expect all three to be the same size. Debugging output is enabled, but not reporting any warnings or errors. Am I missing something, or might this be some sort of driver issue?

Here is the code. The language is Nemerle, but C# and C++ would look almost the same. I have looked through the generated code, and am fairly confident the problem is not language-related.

```
def cpuTexture = Texture2D
    ( device
    , Texture2DDescription() <-
    {
        Width     = 16;
        Height    = 16;
        MipLevels = 1;
        ArraySize = 3;
        Format    = Format.R32_Float;
        Usage     = ResourceUsage.Staging;
        CpuAccessFlags    = CpuAccessFlags.Read;
        SampleDescription = SampleDescription(count = 1, quality = 0);
    }
    );
foreach (subresource in [0 .. 2])
{
    def data = cpuTexture.Map(subresource, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);
    Console.WriteLine($"subresource $subresource");
    Console.WriteLine($"length = $(data.Data.Length)");
    Console.WriteLine($"pitch  = $(data.Pitch)");
    cpuTexture.Unmap(subresource);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for initializing and mapping the texture array?

Comment: @NathanReed, sure, added the code.

Comment: Thanks.  Your code looks right as far as I can see, though, and I checked against the D3D10 docs as well.  I'm afraid I have no idea what's going on. :(

Comment: Is the Texture2D class part of a framework or did you code it yourself? If yes, can you provide the code for cpuTexture.Map(...) ?

Comment: @Djindjidj, it's part of the SlimDX library — a thin wrapper around DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to consider mipLevels.
When creating a texture, usually miplevels will be generated so you will not find texture element 2 at subresource 2 (there is a mipLevel in it, which is half of original texture and so on).

Use this [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb694525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the right subresource index.

```
    ID3D11Texture2D *cpuTexture = NULL;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC cputextdesc;
    memset(&cputextdesc,0,sizeof(cputextdesc));

    cputextdesc.Width = cputextdesc.Height = 16;
    cputextdesc.ArraySize = 3;
    cputextdesc.MipLevels = 1;
    cputextdesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    cputextdesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    cputextdesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    cputextdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    cputextdesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    device->CreateTexture2D(&cputextdesc,NULL,&cpuTexture);

    int text1 = D3D11CalcSubresource(0,0,1);
    int text2 = D3D11CalcSubresource(0,1,1);
    int text3 = D3D11CalcSubresource(0,2,1);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mres1,mres2,mres3;

    icontext->Map(cpuTexture,text1,D3D11_MAP_READ,0,&mres1);
    icontext->Map(cpuTexture,text2,D3D11_MAP_READ,0,&mres2);
    icontext->Map(cpuTexture,text3,D3D11_MAP_READ,0,&mres3);

    // (assert row and depth pitch are equals)

    icontext->Unmap(cpuTexture,text1);
    icontext->Unmap(cpuTexture,text2);
    icontext->Unmap(cpuTexture,text3);
```

Comment: There is only a single mip level.

Comment: I modified my answer with a code example. 3 subresource have the same row and depth pitch.

Comment: Still incorrect because "MipLevels = 1" in the OP, and besides - if it were mipmapping, the lengths would be *quartering*, not halving, for each subresource (the pitch would be expected to - but may not always - halve).  I suspect it's more likely a problem in the calculation of "data.Data.Length" in the OP's environment.

Answer (score 0):

We can begin by stating that this problem is certainly either language-related or a SlimDX bug; it is absolutely **not** a driver bug.  Let's see if we can find out which.

[The canonical implementation of ID3D10Texture2D::Map is described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173869(v=vs.85).aspx), and we see that the method signature is:

```
HRESULT Map(
  [in]  UINT                   Subresource,
  [in]  D3D10_MAP              MapType,
  [in]  UINT                   MapFlags,
  [out] D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D *pMappedTex2D
);
```

When we look at the D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D struct we see that it contains the following members:

```
typedef struct D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D {
  void *pData;
  UINT RowPitch;
} D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D;
```

From this we can categorically state that the Length member you are accessing (`data.Data.Length`) **does not exist** in Microsoft's Direct3D runtime and therefore cannot be provided by the driver.

When we cross-check with [the SlimDX source code](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx/blob/master/source/direct3d10/Texture2D.cpp#L105) we see that the return from `Map` is indeed constructed by SlimDX itself:

```
int mipHeight = GetMipSize( mipSlice, desc.Height );
int sizeInBytes = mipHeight * mappedRect.RowPitch;
if (Utilities::IsCompressed(desc.Format))
    sizeInBytes /= 4;

return gcnew SlimDX::DataRectangle( mappedRect.RowPitch, gcnew DataStream( mappedRect.pData, sizeInBytes, true, true, false ) );
```

**This is therefore a SlimDX bug**.

Looking over the SlimDX code I've linked I don't immediately see anything that could cause it, so I would suggest updating you download of SlimDX as a first troubleshooting step, as it may be a bug that has been fixed by a more recent version.

Comment: There is a good chance it was fixed in the five years since I asked the question. :)